# Polymorphic r-value references?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, rvalue-reference

If I wanted to store a polymorphic object in a class, my first thought would be to something like  the following:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "Base !";
    }
};

struct Derived: public Base {
    void print() const {
        std::cout << "Derived !";
    }
};

struct PolymorphicWrapper {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base;
};
```

The problem with `std::unique_ptr<Base>` is that it leads to complex ownership issues and pointer semantics. While references / raw pointers can have polymorphic behaviour, they cannot bind to r-values.

However I just discovered that r-value references were polymorphic!!

Eg:

```
Base && base = Derived();
base.print(); // Derived !

Base&& base2 = Base();
base2.print(); // Base !
```

I can even store an r - value reference in a class!

```
struct PolymorphicWrapper {
     Base&& base;
     PolymorphicWrapper(auto iBase) : base(std::move(iBase)) {} // auto to prevent object slicing
};
```

However, this seems almost too good to be true. Am I missing something here? Is this an example of undefined behaviour?

Comment: The real question if the lifetime of the object you are trying to bind to. Whatever the reference (even if it is a raw pointer), if the object reaches its end of life before you use the reference, you will get a dangling ref (or pointer).

Comment: @SergeBallesta in my understanding, when a temporary is bound to a r-value reference, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime to a r-value reference.

Comment: A unique_ptr does not "lead" to complex ownership issues. It simply makes poorly thought out ownership semantics stand out. The reference is no better. It just silently lets bugs creep in.

Comment: Lifetime is not extended for reference members.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica What if I don't want to allocate on the heap?

Comment: @Jarod42 What do you mean by that? For me, assigning a temporary to the r-value reference works just fine...

Comment: Where an object's storage comes comes from has little correlation with deciding how it's owned. You are thinking about smart pointers in terms of what they do (delete), instead of the semantics they enforce. That's why it seems hard.

Comment: In your example `iBase` dies at the end of the constructor. The stored reference is left dangling.

Comment: @Quentin I thought that r-value references could bind to r-values, and std::move created an r - value. Could you explain why I have a dangling reference?

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica I meant for performance reasons, or sometimes I don't even have a heap...

Comment: With `base(std::move(iBase))` `iBase`'s lifetime is not extended, `base` is dangling reference.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok, thanks for explaining. How do I cast iBase into an r-value and extend its lifetime?

Comment: You cannot.....

Comment: @Jarod42 Say I create clone function,  which takes one object, which just returns the object by value. Calling the function creates an r-value, right? Which my r-value reference could bind to? Or is there an error in my reasoning?

Comment: Rvalue references are not a magic replacement for the heap. There is no magic replacement for the heap. If you don't have a heap, you cannot create an object that outlives the function that creates it.

Comment: When you write something like `PolymorphicWrapper w(Derived())`, you have a temporary that binds to the constructor argument `iBase`. The lifetime of the temporary is thus extended to the lifetime of `iBase`, that is, not too much. `iBase` is not a temporary, so there is no further lifetime extension. Even if you create a temporary out of `iBase` by e.g. copying it, you cannot extend its lifetime too much, see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) and [this](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1696).

Comment: Polymorphic clone return (smart) pointer, not by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::move` creates an rvalue *reference* to an existing lvalue, which marks it explicitly as ready to be moved from. You can initialize another rvalue reference from that, however you are *not* in the special lifetime-extension case for two reasons:

- It requires an actual rvalue (i.e. an object that was just constructed within the expression and never passed through a reference);
- More importantly, it does not apply to reference members at all.

> **Note**: I'm reasonably sure that I've got this right, but I cannot seem to find a standard quote, probably because I'm getting lost in the aggregate initialization and temporary materialization wording. Language lawyers welcome.

Therefore you're just storing a reference to the constructor's parameter, which dies at the end of said constructor and leavs the reference dangling.

Note that when storing an arbitrary type-erased object as a member you cannot avoid dynamic allocation in the general case, if only because the dynamic type's size is unknown and unbounded. `std::unique_ptr` is the first choice for this case, but you could also design your own type-erasing container with small object storage if you wanted.